# Create shell script that just runs

Tags: bash, shell, loops

How would I create a simple shell script that doesn't do anything, just runs forever, without overloading the CPU. I am using an [appify](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/shell-script-mac-apps) script to make it into an app, so that I can have an app that just runs forever. The reason I do this is so that I can always have an app running and therefore quit out of finder without it opening back up again.

**Note:** to allow quitting out of finder, run the command `defaults write com.apple.finder QuitMenuItem -bool yes` in terminal.

Comment: `while(true); do sleep 1 ;done`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you could create a job that would sleep forever and just wait on it:

```
sleep forever &
wait
```

but in reality you have to pick a finite amount of time to sleep.

```
while :; do
    sleep 65535 &
    wait
done
```

This will only use minimal CPU every 18 hours or so to restart the `sleep` process. There is probably an upper limit to the size of the argument you can give to `sleep`, but I don't know what that is (and it is probably implementation-dependent). You can experiment; a larger number will reduce total CPU usage over the life of the program, but even calling `sleep` once an hour (every 3600 seconds) will use very little CPU.